# Update only specific rows in a dataframe in a Shiny App

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

So I was trying to build a shiny app to calculate the distance for a particular trip in real time. I will be getting the data in real time for every 15secs and gets updated in a dataframe `df1`. For this, I need to store the values that I get in the first 15secs in another dataframe `cal_distdf` in the first row.

Subsequently, when I get the newly updated data in `df1` at next 15secs, the second row of `cal_distdf` should be replaced. **NOTE:** First row of the `cal_distdf` remains the same throughout the application and only second row gets updated for every 15secs.

Below is my R script.

```
cal_distdf <- df1$Odovalue

distcal <- reactive({

       cal_distdf[2] <- df1$Odovalue
       disttravelled <- cal_distdf[2] - cal_distdf[1]

      return(disttravelled)
})

output$Distance <- renderText({distcal()})
```

Here in my code, I am failing to store the previous value of the `df1`. So how do I store the previous values of `df1` throughout the application?

Comment: The way to update a specific cell in a dataframe is `df[row,col] <- newValue`. Your `cal_distdf` should be a vector (not a dataframe), but is it?

Comment: @Rodrigo, Well I want it to be a data frame Calculating distance is not the only operation I will be performing.

Comment: `df <- data.frame(col1 = numeric(), col2 = character(), ..., stringsAsFactors=F)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `reactiveValues()` to create a data frame initially. Further, you can use `isolate()` while appending new rows to the `cal_distdf`, well instead of changing only specific row values you can append the rows with new values and take the difference between the first value and the latest appended value.

```
#Create New dataframe
values <- reactiveValues()
values$cal_distdf <- data.frame(Odovalue = numeric(0))

 #Function to calculate distance

distcal <- reactive({

   newdistvalue <- df1$Odovalue #Store the new value to a variable
   newrow <- isolate(c(newdistvalue)) 
   isolate( values$cal_distdf [nrow( values$cal_distdf ) + 1,] <- c(newLine)) #append new row to the existing dataframe. NOTE using rbind() changes the column name.
   newdistvalue1 <-  values$cal_distdf #Copying appended rows dataframe to new data frame. 
   cal_dist <- as.numeric(tripd$Odovalue[nrow(newdistvalue1)]) - as.numeric(newdistvalue1$Odovalue[1]) # Calculating difference between new appended row with the first row value to Calculate distance
  return(cal_dist)

})

 output$Distance <- renderText({distcal()})
```

Hope this helps.